# pip3 install -r requirements.txt - Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-a0nd7us1/post/

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

When I try `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` I get the error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-a0nd7us1/post/
```

It seems to me that I have tried everything. Any suggestions? I have Python 3.6.1 in virtualenv.

This is my `requirements.txt` file:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
asn1crypto==0.22.0
base==1.0.4
cffi==1.10.0
cryptography==1.8.1
Django==1.11
django-cors-headers==2.0.2
djangorestframework==3.6.2
get==0.0.0
idna==2.5
inflection==0.3.1
Keras==2.0.4
modules==1.0.0
more-itertools==3.0.0
mysqlclient==1.3.10
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.2
numpy==1.12.1
packaging==16.8
pandas==0.19.2
post==0.0.0
props==0.0.2
protobuf==3.2.0
public==0.0.0
pyasn1==0.2.3
pycparser==2.17
pyOpenSSL==17.0.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2017.2
PyYAML==3.12
Quandl==3.1.0
query-string==0.0.0
request==0.0.0
requests==2.13.0
scipy==0.19.0
setupfiles==0.0.0
simplejson==3.10.0
six==1.10.0
tensorflow==1.1.0
Theano==0.9.0
virtualenv==15.1.0
Werkzeug==0.12.1
```

**SOLVED: I left only the necessary dependencies and everything works fine.**

Comment: What's in the requirements.txt file? could you put it in the quest?

Comment: I get `It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.`, how can I avoid this?

Comment: hahahaha fantastic.... sure... try to write also with bullets everything you tryed step by step, in resume, not everything, and then add the requiremets.txt. If you can't, add a link to a pick or something

Comment: Okey, I have updated my post.

Comment: It has 42 lines? I'm seeing ok?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure whether all are necessary. Maybe there is any solution to check what is not needed. But the only idea that comes to my mind is to delete all 42 lines, check errors in terminal during `python manage.py runserver` and installing all needed dependencies. Is it a good solution? Maybe it will help.

Comment: Please post more of the error traceback you're getting; showing us just the last line tells us practically nothing.  Can you at least determine which package the failure happens on?

Answer (score 0):

After creating you venv, try to:

(yourVEnv)$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python

Then deactivate then reactivate your virtual environment. Do this or pip won't work correctly.

```
(yourVEnv)$ deactivate
$ source myvenv/bin/activate
(yourVEnv)$ which pip
```

or Check it with

```
(yourVEnv)$pip -V
```

then do you

```
pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt
```

Don't forget to add the full path to your requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

As distribute has been merged back into setuptools, it is now recommended to install/upgrade setuptools instead:

```
[sudo] pip install --upgrade setuptools
```